# How to choose first match from Alternation regex?

Tags: python, regex, tweepy, tweets

I am trying to extract all the text from the tweets before the URL starting with "https:...".

Example Tweet:

> "This traditional hairdo is back in fashion thanks to the coronavirus, and Kenyans are using it to raise awareness https://... (Video via @QuickTake)"

In this example I would like to remove the "https://... (Video via @QuickTake)" and get the text from the beginning. **But it should also work for when the tweet comes without any URL link in the tweet text.**

I have tried this expression and gets two matches for when it comes with URL:

```
/(.*)(?=\shttps.*)|(.*)
```

How can I make it to retrieve only the text from the tweets.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to remove all after http, `tweet = re.sub(r'\s*https.*', '', tweet)`

Comment: Perfect, that solves it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove the `https` and all tha follows till the end of string, use

```
tweet = re.sub(r'\s*https.*', '', tweet)
```

Details:

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `https` - a string
- `.*` - the rest of the string (line).

Answer (score 0):

This might be an oversimplification, but a simple `str.find` might do the trick:

```py
>>> s = "This traditional hairdo is back in fashion thanks to the coronavirus, and Kenyans are using it to raise awareness https://... (Video via @QuickTake)"
>>> s[:s.find('https://')]
'This traditional hairdo is back in fashion thanks to the coronavirus, and Kenyans are using it to raise awareness '
```

You basically just index the tweet until the point at which you find the first instance of `https://`.

Note that approach alone won't work in the case of `https://` not appearing in a tweet. When `https://` isn't found, `s.find('https://')` will return -1, which will mess up our indexing. If it's not found, just set the indexer (`link_index` below) to the length of the full tweet:

```py
>>> s = 'this is some tweet without a URL'
>>> link_index = s.find('https://')
>>> if link_index == -1:
...     link_index = len(s)
... 
>>> s[:link_index]
'this is some tweet without a URL'
```